Why does enp5s0 show a static AND dynamic ipv4 address when I have set dhcp4 to no in netplan yaml file?
I am using Ubuntu 24.04. I have networkd as the renderer, with Network Manager disabled.
I have a few NUCs all using networkd and all with enp5s0 dhcp4 set to no.
One of the NUCs (only 1 so far, I have tested 6) has a static ip address that I set, but also has a dynamic ip address. This messes up a job on Rundeck, as I use the ip address for part of the filename. The filename can only consist of one ip address.
My /etc/netplan/01-static-usb.yaml file is the same on all NUC's.
I found the file /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp5s0.network was different for this particular NUC.
It included the line DHCP=ipv4 under the heading [Network] and also has a heading titled [DHCP], which the other NUC's don't have in this file.
I have deleted this file, but it automatically returns. I have removed the extra lines form the file, but when I sudo netplan apply, the lines return.
Is there a reason that this happens? Have I missed something on this particular NUC?
This is the 01-static-enp5s0.yaml file that I created:
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp5s0:
      dhcp4: no
      addresses: [10.33.33.31/24]
      routes:
        - to: 10.33.33.31
          via: 10.33.33.1
      match:
        macaddress: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XY
      set-name: enp5s0
    eno1:
      dhcp4: yes
      optional: yes
      match: 
        macaddress: XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XX
      set-name: eno1

This is the /run/systemd/network/10-netplan-enp5s0.yaml file that is automatically generated:
[Match]
PermanentMACAddress=XX:XX:XX:XX:XX:XY
Name=enp5s0

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=10.33.33.31/24

[Route]
Destination=10.33.33.31
Gateway=10.33.33.1

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTC=true


